# how to dynamically debug all urls of website with facebook debugger

Tags: facebook

When i am like post from my webpage with facebook like button, then  it opens share post window..in this window image of page which i am liking, is  not displaying image on liked post.
but when i copied and paste this page url in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/  and retry to like that web page  then it will displays correct image.

But problem is that my site have lots of dynamic pages so how can i manually debug all pages??.
Is there any way to debug all urls dynamic or crawl automatic ?